Prevent teamcity mail notifications upon developing
In teamcity we have builds that are use for both regressions and for developing.
I want that when scheduled trigger (regression) is running the build it will send mail notifications, otherwise it won't send mail or will send just to the developer that ran it.

If developer check the run as a personal build (Run Custom Build -> General) when he running his none regression test, mail notification will be sent just to him and it won't be shown to others in the build list.
